# Scrapy + Celery more tasks I needed

Tags: python, scrapy, celery

I have more log with stats than logs with successful celery task, why? Does this mean that some of my old tasks are not killed?

I have following 8 log lines in celery worker log file:

```
Task track_new_items[<id>] succeeded in <time>s: None
```

But I have following 19 lines:

```
[scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
<stats_dict>
```

This logs are sent every time when spider was closed.

I run my task by following code:

```
from billiard.context import Process
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


class CrawlerScript:
    def __init__(self, settings=None):
        if settings is None:
            settings = get_project_settings()
        self.crawler = CrawlerProcess(settings)

    def _crawl(self):
        self.crawler.start()
        self.crawler.stop()

    def crawl(self, spider_cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self.crawler.crawl(spider_cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        p = Process(target=self._crawl)
        p.start()
        p.join()

@shared_task()
def track_new_items():
    crawler = CrawlerScript()
    crawler.crawl(<spider>)
    crawler.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by `--max-tasks-per-child 1`.

Who can explain why without this arg celery run several some tasks?